# ElasticSearch - Get different types from different indices

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, elastic4s

I have two indices: `A` and `B`.

`A` has the following types: `car`, `motorbike` and `van`.

`B` has the following types: `bus`, `car` and `pickup`.

I want to be able to have a single query which gets `motorbike` and `van` from `A` and `car` and `pickup` from `B`.

I want to use a `filter` to do this and currently, I have:

```
.filter(
   not(
      should(
         termsQuery("key", Seq("car", "bus"))
      )
   )
)
```

But obviously, this will filter `car` for both indices. I know I can do two separate queries for each index and filter different types for each but I want to avoid this if possible.

Is it possible to do what I am trying to do in a single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search on index and type by using the special fields `_index` and `_type` so once you know that, it's just a matter of putting together a boolean query.

```
  search("_all").query(
    boolQuery().should(
      boolQuery().must(
        termQuery("_index", "A"),
        termsQuery("_type", "motorbike", "van")
      ),
      boolQuery().must(
        termQuery("_index", "B"),
        termsQuery("_type", "car", "pickup")
      )
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "_index": {
                    "value": "A"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "terms": {
                  "_type":  ["motorbike","van"]

                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "_index": {
                    "value": "B"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "terms": {
                  "_type": ["car","pickup"]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```